# Obtaining average value around polygon in raster for different cross sections?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, dem, spatial-analyst, elevation, flood

I have elevation data in a raster, river (blue line) and the flooded area (black polygon) as shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to find the water depth in the flooded area (inside the black polygon). Outside of the polygon, water depth is obviously zero. Inside the polygon, the land elevation is lower than outside (At least it should be)

What I tried to do and did NOT work was this: I assigned nodata value to the points inside the polygon. Then I used Eucilidean Allocation to find the closest points just outside the polygon and assign it to nodata points. Then, I Subtracted the original land elevation raster from this new raster. However, I get big negative values because after all, it was not a good method at all.

Now, I am thinking: I need to follow the water stream line. At each point, draw a perpendicular line to the river and let it intersect minimum two times with the polygon. Find the average value of cells inside a circle (with those intersections as center). Find the mean of these averages. apply this value too all points in that cross section (perpendicular line to the river). Now, is there any way on earth I can do this? Hopefully I don't need a for loop for this? Do you guys have any other suggestions, perhaps easier ways?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 with Spatial Analyst and 3D Analyst extensions.

Comment: Just an observation, how did you get accurate points inside a watercourse? is it non-perennial? I regularly process LiDAR data and most sensors will not penetrate water. To give elevation inside a waterbody triangulation is applied but it's nowhere near accurate and takes the closest dry point and stretches it over the water area.

Comment: Does your polygon have z information? Your approach is correct - you need to create a surface raster out of the flood area elevation and then subtract the original from it to get the difference, or flood depth. What kind of 'big negative values' are you getting? I'm thinking your creation of the new flood surface raster might have had an issue.

Comment: Michael, You are absolutely right. The accuracy of the DEM inside of river channels are questionable. I am trying to do the best I can to get the flood depth from the extent polygon I have.

Comment: Chris! My polygon does not have z information. The negative values are due to very large size of grids (10x10 m).

Comment: Here's an idea! What do you guys think?

1) I make the points inside the polygon nodata.
2) I use Con(IsNull("raster_nodata_inside"),FocalStatistics("raster_nodata_inside",NBrRectangle(3,3),"MAX"),"raster_nodata_inside")
3) Now we have the boundaries all right. I use Eucilidean Allocation to do the rest.

Does that work?

Comment: Is your goal to get the water depth at the streamline center? Depth at all points within the polygon? Average depth for some spatial area within the polygon? I am not sure why you would use the Euclidean Allocation with this; if you want to explore only the depth profile of land within the polygon, then [Clip Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009n000000) would probably meet your needs much more reliably.

Comment: @Erica I believe asker looking to create a difference raster (depth) between existing elevation and flood elevation, but only has an existing elevation raster and a 2D flood boundary polygon. Clip would cut out a portion of a raster, but the crux here (which I don't know how to do off hand) is to generate the flood surface raster that could then be used to get the difference raster. That's what EA is being proposed for - create the flood surface based on the nearest cell outside the boundary.

Comment: @ChrisW, that's hydro-flattening. Trust me when I say it's not that easy. I put two months into developing, refining and testing a hydro-flattening program... and have the scars to prove it! For this simple model I think you should get the elevation onto the line, make a terrain from it then terrain to raster, extract by the original polygon and then difference that. If that makes sense let me know and I'll write it up as an answer with better descriptions.

Comment: Chris! That makes sense. At this point, I am convinced that this simple model does not work most likely. I am not gonna do it for now as it seems that it requires much more time than I expected.

Comment: user33020 - I would encourage you not to give up just yet. I think Michael's solution wouldn't take all that long and it's a good analysis to know how to do. @MichaelMiles-Stimson Good to know a name for it to search on for further reading. Yes, I would go ahead and write up an answer if you have the time. I kept trying to think of a one-step solution for creating the flood raster, but your two-step makes a lot of sense. This is a pretty fundamental hydrology analysis, so I'm definitely interested in seeing ways to do it.

Comment: @ChrisW, I've put that in as an answer.

Comment: @Chris and @Michael! I will give this a try and post the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you would need a 3d Analyst and Spatial Analyst license.

First, elevate your waterbody using [Interpolate Shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Interpolate_Shape/00q90000006m000000/), this will give the baseline for your elevations by attributing the polygon with the Z values from the DEM to each vertex.

Build a [terrain](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005v00000002000000.htm) with your waterbodies as the elevation data source (perhaps buffer by a small amount and include that as *hard clip*) and use [Extract by Mask](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002n000000.htm) to get only the water area by using the waterbodies as the mask; we only want the elevation inside the waterbodies because, as you said, outside the waterbody boundary the depth is 0.

Convert your terrain to raster using [Terrain to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q90000002t000000) which will give raster inside the waterbodies at the same level as the baseline (edges).

Now do [raster calculation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) and subtract the original DEM with the rivers. The difference raster should be now the depth of the water, or more correctly the bed below the bank.

Comment: I have a problem with building the terrain from the elevated waterbody. "Build terrain" function does not accept my elevated waterbody as input. Here's the code I use to make the elevated waterbody: `arcpy.InterpolateShape_3d(DEM, Flood_extent_shp, waterbody_elevated_shp, "", "1", "BILINEAR", "DENSIFY", "0")`